# jdk win xp could not create java virtual machine

Tags: java, windows-xp

I installed jdk 7 on windows xp sp2 x64 pro. When I try to run any java program I get a message:

```
Could not create Java virtual machine.
```

I tried most common solution, that is changing heap size to 512 but it didn't help.

Please help.

Comment: follow this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075628/could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-caused-by-virus-or-machine-is-messed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the program from the command prompt? You might be able to find more information in that way.